# Instamojo Integration Issue

Tags: swift4, xcode10, instamojo

I have integrated Instamojo in my project and working on xcode 10, swift version 4. I am following [Instamojo Documentation](https://docs.instamojo.com/v1.1/page/ios-integration) site for integration  and facing below error.

> /Volumes/.../Instamojo
>   Integration/Pods/InstaMojoiOS/InstaMojoiOS-Release-iphoneuniversal/InstaMojoiOS.framework/InstaMojoiOS
>   compiled with older version of Swift language (4.0) than previous
>   files (unknown ABI version 0x06) file '/Volumes/.../Instamojo
>   Integration/Pods/InstaMojoiOS/InstaMojoiOS-Release-iphoneuniversal/InstaMojoiOS.framework/InstaMojoiOS'
>   for architecture x86_64.

Please help me in this. Waiting for positive response. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Your instamojo podfile is older one. Update the newer version no of your podfile and reinstall it.